# Android JAVA RX exception only from the play store

Tags: java, android, system.reactive

Hello everyone i have this exception from RX on my google play console, i've have never see it on my project but it occurred about 200 times as google play says... any one has an idea about that ?

**java.lang.IllegalStateException:**

```
 at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run (LooperScheduler.java:114)

  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7230)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)

**Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException:** 

  at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError (SafeSubscriber.java:187)

  at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError (SafeSubscriber.java:115)

  at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport (Exceptions.java:216)

  at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext (SafeSubscriber.java:139)

  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext (OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101)

  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call (OperatorObserveOn.java:224)

  at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run (LooperScheduler.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing an exception that is not caught.

Have you specified an function for onError?

```
   [Your Observable].subscribe(value -> {
        // Your onNext code
    }, throwable -> {
        // Handle error
    });
```